# How to create Single DataFrame for multiple Phoenix (HBase tables) in Java?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql, apache-phoenix

I have a scenario where I have multiple HBase tables on Phoenix and I have to create a single dataframe from these multiple Phoenix tables? Can anyone please provide me the solution to achieve this using Java ?